# Is there a way to lock a program after X attempted logins?

Tags: c#, winforms, security

This is just a quick question as I haven't been able to find anything about this topic yet.

I have been asked to add a feature to a program that will render the program useless or for lack of another term "dead" after X amount of incorrect logins, kind of like an iPhone locking itself for a period of time when you type your passcode in wrong.

Only thing is I've no idea as to how I can make a program effectively lock itself down permanently while its still running. Is it even possible to do so or would you need to have some sort of background operation that does it for you?

Comment: `if(passwordFailure){exit;}`? What have you tried to do ?

Comment: @scrappedcola i haven't tried anything as of yet as I have zero experience with this type of problem nor have I been able to find any type of information on it either here on stack or MSDN or on google in general.

Comment: Well what are you trying to solve? You need the program to kick the user after x number of invalid logins. So what's the first step? Identify when a user no longer can log in and store that somewhere. What's the next step you need? To either close the program or not proceed to the next set of screens. So identify these steps and try something. You know where the login occurs so start there.

Comment: @scrappedcola thanks I'll try a few things and see if they get me the result thats needed.

Comment: Add an event handler to the login class that track number of failure and fire the event and exit the application.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to find any system API to kill the program or lock it, what you've been asked to do is just another feature for your software, which if you think about it you have almost already implemented.

You have a program that does a certain number of things, but only after a login screen. That means your program does not really "work" unless you log in correctly. The program runs, but the user can't interact with anything other than the login screen.

What you do now is, after a number of failed logins, you don't even provide the login form. Instead show an error message in whichever shape or form you want. Your program is still running, is not really "dead", but you can consider it locked since there is nothing users can do.

If you were to exit the program abruptly instead, it would look more like an unexpected error, and also would prevent you from doing things like removing the lock (showing the login form again) after a period of time, etc..

Comment: Might need to add flashing scrolling text that the reason they can't get in is failed logins...users don't read a thing